# Web app losing local storage when run from Home Screen iOS 11.3

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, sencha-touch, ios11.3

We have a java script web application. We store user credentials in local storage, so that the users stay logged in/do not need to enter their credentials every time they run the app.

The web app is run by adding to home screen, and running from there.

Recently some of our clients moved to iOS 11.3, and of those, some lose their credentials/local storage when the web app is run from home screen. The app has been in production for 5 years now, and nothing has changed as far as saving credentials to local storage goes during this time.

Going to Safari and running from there works perfectly fine (local storage is retained). This is the current workaround for them. But obviously, running from home screen is preferable due to ease of use, no URL bars taking up space, and also we want to have one method (run from home screen) for all our users.

We have tried all the usual basic things to resolve this - deleting bookmark, re-adding bookmark to home screen, rebooting devices, etc.

Is this behavior expected now for iOS 11.3 and higher? (But again, this is only happening on some iOS 11.3 devices, not all - just to give you an idea on scale, there are approximately 40 users so far that have updated to iOS 11.3, of these only 3 exhibit the above issue). What can we do if we want want to retain local storage when run from home screen?

Comment: can you please post the javascript code that you have used to save the credentials?

Comment: sounds like it could be this issue (local storage getting dumped when storage is low) https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/64